# How to include bigger board into smaller one? c++

Tags: c++

id like to include smaller pieces, like in a [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKLkx.png) below, into this board, and i have no idea how.

```
void O()
{
   for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
           cout<<"O";
       cout<<endl;
   }

}
void Draw()
{
   system("cls");
   int z = 10;
   for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
   {
       if (((i+2)%3==0)&&(z == 10))
       {
           cout<<z<<"";
           --z;
       }
       else if (((i+2)%3==0)&&(z<10))
       {
           cout<<z<<" ";
           --z;
       } //wypisywanie cyfr
       else cout<<"  ";
       for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
       {
           if (j%5==0){
               if (i%3==0) cout<<"@";
               else cout<<"!";
           }
           if ((i%3==0)) cout<<"=";
           else if ((i <= h1.y) && (j <= h1.x))H();
           else cout<<" ";


       }
       cout<<endl;  //tabelka
   }
       cout<<"     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J"<<endl;

}
int main()
{
  Draw();
  O();
   return 0;
}
```

I've tried code this as a function. Maybe I should do it with some arrays, but still i don't know how i'd have to start.

Comment: Why does your `O` function output `endl`'s in the middle of the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Figure out how many lines your board display is.
2. Figure out how many characters your board display is.
3. Create a loop that repeats for the number of lines you have.
4. In the loop, look at the line number and determine which type of line it is. Write a separate inner loop for each type of line.
5. If it's the first, second to last, other separator line, output the correct    `+-----+----...` line.
6. If it's one of the inner board lines:
   6A) Output either three spaces or the correct line number.
   6B) Output a `|`.
   6C) Loop over the columns outputting either three spaces, three #'s, or three O's with a '|' in-between.
   6D) Output the ending `|`.
7. If it's the last line, output the correct      `A     B     C ....` line.
8. Output a newline after each line, then loop and do the next line.

Here's some sample code:

```
void display_board(char board[10][10])
{
    char rn = '9';
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; ++i)
    {
        int type = i % 3;
        if (type == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "   +";
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
                std::cout << "-----+";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (type == 1)
                std::cout << "   |";
            else if (i == 2)
                std::cout << " 10|";
            else
                std::cout << " " << rn-- << " |";
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                char c = board[i/3][j];
                std::cout << " " << c << c << c << " |";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        
    }
    std::cout <<
    "     A      B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J"
        << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char board[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            board[i][j] = ' ';
    board[0][3] = '#';
    board[0][6] = '#';
    board[3][0] = '#';
    board[3][9] = '#';
    board[6][0] = 'O';
    board[6][9] = 'O';
    board[9][3] = 'O';
    board[9][6] = 'O';
    display_board(board);
}
```

See it work [here](https://onlinegdb.com/jzC-TPXAy).